# How to connect appium to an extended Selenium Grid?

Tags: selenium, appium

I've created a class to extend the selenium grid following the directions here: https://www.swtestacademy.com/extend-selenium-grid
Connecting selenium nodes is not a problem (as long as I extended selenium version 3.12 [3.141.59 won't allow connections]).  My issue is that I can't connect an appium node.

I run the server and nodes on the same machine.
Server command: java -jar selenium-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -role hub

Appium Node command: appium -p 4723 --nodeconfig node.json

```
node.json:
{  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "com.swtestacademy.ExtendedProxy",
  "maxSession": 1,
  "port": -1,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://localhost:4444/grid/register",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

[Appium] Request to register with grid was unsuccessful: 500 - "\n\n\nError 500 Server Error\n\n

### HTTP ERROR 500

\n

Problem accessing /grid/register. Reason:\n

```
    Server Error
```

#### Caused by:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException\r\n\tat org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.RegistrationServlet.considerV2Json(RegistrationServlet.java:172)\r\n\tat org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.RegistrationServlet.process(RegistrationServlet.java:97)\r\n\tat org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.RegistrationServlet.doPost(RegistrationServlet.java:70)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)\r\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\r\n
```

\n

---

http://eclipse.org/jetty\">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT

---

\n\n\n\n"

Comment: I'm wondering if I need to create some custom registration servlet since java.lang.NullPointerException\r\n\tat org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.RegistrationServlet.considerV2Json(RegistrationServlet.java:172)

Answer (score 0):

It seem like you miss `--address` to server address, and `-role node` argument to excute `-nodeConfig` options.

Try run the node with this command:

```
appium --address 127.0.0.1 -role node -nodeConfig node.json
```

`-a` or `--address`

See:

[Node Configuration](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#node-configuration)

[Appium Server Arguments](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/server-args/#appium-server-arguments)

Comment: Thanks but it sill didn't work.  I received the same 500 error.  The address and role are specified in the node.json. I confirmed that I could connect appium to the standard selenium jar server before connecting to the custom server.